# The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint the error shows when i delete it in the procedures

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `tb1` which is a parent table and child table `tb2`. My parent table has a column `pid` and it is referred to `tb2 cpid` as a foreign key `FK_name` for `cpid`.

When I delete from the child table first and then the parent table manually, it's working fine. But when I do it inside a procedure, I get an error

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_name".
>   The conflict occurred in database "database Name", table "childTablename""

Can anyone help me resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

```
Delete tb2
Delete tb1
```

In your procedure make sure your are doing this.

Comment: Yes i am deleting the child table first only after that i am doing the parent table

Comment: Can you give your procedure code and then  make sure the child table is not being referenced by any other table.